# How to create a Very VERY Simple proxy to a specific page/feed

Tags: php

I have a simple problem. Living in Ch*na we don't have access to much of the social media sites. So I want to create a php file that fetches the content of a blocked rss file and output's itself as that rss.

unblockedserver.com/twittfeed.php?id=23038034

```
<?php
$id  = (int)$_GET['id'];
$url='http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/'.$id .'.rss';
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"); 
$feed = getthecontentfromthe($url);? // what goes here?

echo $feed;
```

The main site handles the caching and generally the url/page will be a secret, so i hope this will be simple enough.
Cheers

Comment: You might need to use a secure connection (HTTPS) to your server to evade keyword-based filtering.

Comment: @idealmachine I would agree, but we're not trying to get any political messages through, just harmless social media marketing bla and the CCP is not really against those aspects of twitter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
readfile($url);
```

instead of your latest 2 lines.